# Importing content with feedme to single entry in 3 locales

Tags: localization, plugin-feedme

This is the situation:

- I've got 3 locales (en, nl, fr)
- I've got an XML file with content in those 3 locales
- I've set up the field mapping in feedme

But what I can't seem to figure out is how to import the entries from the XML file into combined entries in Craft, meaning, I want elements from my XML file (the same content in 3 locales) to be 1 craft entry in those 3 locales.

Each time I do the import, I'm stuck with all of them being in the same locale.

Let me know if any additional information is needed.

Any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I managed to do the import

Create extra field on entry to save common ID (will be used to link 3 locales together)

Set up feed for each locale with following settings:
- import strategy: create & update
- newly created field as unique identifier

Run each import separately

Feedme will than for the first locale create the entries, and for following locales, update the first one if the id field matches & add the translation to the entry.

Comment: I'm trying to follow these instructions but things aren't working for me – I've made a common ID field and confirmed it matches across both locales. I did the first import against locale 1, then set the second import to "update only" against locale 2. It makes no changes and says it couldn't find a match. Did you come up against this at all?